# How to dismiss progress dialog when i'm moving to another activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm starting a new Activity in `OnPostExecute` and call `pDialog.dismiss()` , but when I'm coming back from the new Activity to the previous Activity - the progress dialog is still running.
How do I dismiss it permanently at the moment I'm moving to another activity ?

Here is my AsyncTask Class.

```
public class FindRideTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
     private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if(pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing())
        {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FindRideBoard.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("Results", ridesList);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FindRide.this);
        pDialog.show(FindRide.this, "מתחבר לשרת", "אנא המתן");
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        s_ParseLogic = ParseLogic.getInstance();

        try
        {
            ArrayList<ParseObject> ridesFromQuery = (ArrayList<ParseObject>)s_ParseLogic.FindRides(sourceList.getText().toString(), destinationList.getText().toString(), time_picker.getText().toString(), m_date.getText().toString());
            ridesList = new ArrayList<Ride>();

            for(int i = 0 ; i < ridesFromQuery.size() ; i++)
            {
                ParseObject obj = ridesFromQuery.get(i);
                ridesList.add(new Ride((String)obj.get("Source"), (String)obj.get("Destination"), (String)obj.get("Day"),(String) obj.get("Time"), (String)obj.get("IsPermanent"), (String)obj.get("Driver"), (String)obj.get("Driver Phone"))) ;
            }
        }
        catch(ParseException e)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: use the `pDialog.dismiss();` in before the intent call at postexecute().

Comment: `pDialog.dismiss();` should be your first statement in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: I've tried this before. it's still running :(

Comment: Is this AsyncTask an inner class in an activity? Are you sure you haven't shown any other Progress Dialog than this in previous activity? Recheck once

Comment: Yes. it's an inner class in an activity. This progress dialog is the only one that i have and its defined inside the AsyncTask class.

Answer (score 1):

Here `getApplicationContext()` is a `Context` of your `Application`. So change with

```
  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivityName.this);
```

And in `onPostExecute()` method

```
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

   if(pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing()){

     pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FindRideBoard.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("Results", ridesList);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

`UPDATE`:

Destroy your `ProgressDialog` in `onDestroy()` method of your `Activity`.

```
 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
     if(pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing()){

     pDialog.dismiss();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is your AsyncTask is a seperate class?

Comment: My AsyncTask is a class inside my Activity which inherits from FragmentActivity

Comment: @Sharon182 So somewhere you missing something or something wrong because generally i have also used same this way but i haven't faced this type of problem. So just check your code step by step.

Comment: The problem is solved if i call to pDialog.show() without any parameters. Any clue of what's wrong ?

Comment: Yes because you have to seperatly set message and title when you uses  `pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FindRide.this);` and that time use `pDialog.show()`. Another way is for use  `pDialog = new  pDialog.show(FindRide.this, "מתחבר לשרת", "אנא המתן");`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like @X'Factor said, but dismiss the dialog in your activity's onStop() methodm which get called when the activity is no longer visible.

```
@Override
 protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
     if(pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing()){

     pDialog.dismiss();
    }
 }
```

Also check if you're starting your AsyncTask in the Activity's **onResume()** which may cause the dialog to appear in first place.